# Pronunciation of en- prefix as ahn-

Tags: pronunciation, prefixes

Recently, I pronounced the word *enqueue* as *ahn-queue*.  The person I was talking to said he would have pronounced it with a more normal *en* sound (like in Ben or den).

I'm not sure why I thought that *ahn-* was the way to pronounce this—it seems to be wrong according to the dictionary.

The cases that *ahn-* seems to be correct are two-word french phrases (e.g., [*en route*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/en+route)).  I also thought of [*envoy*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/envoy), which does allow the *ahn-* pronunciation as a second option.

Is there a pattern for which words allow or require *en-* to be pronounced as *ahn-*?  Or is this just something you have to know word-by-word?

Comment: I encourage this ensemble of ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of *en-* words that can be pronounced /an/ rather than /ɪn/ or /ɛn/ is pretty short. From a quick search of the [Carnegie-Mellon Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict), these words start with *en-* and can be pronounced /an/ (some have alternate pronunciations with /ɛn/):

```
ENCLAVE
ENCLAVES
ENCORE
ENCORES
ENFANT
ENSEMBLE
ENSEMBLES
ENTENDRE
ENTOURAGE
ENTOURAGES
ENTRE
ENTREE
ENTREES
ENTREPRENEUR
ENTREPRENEUR'S
ENTREPRENEURIAL
ENTREPRENEURS
ENTREPRENEURSHIP
ENVOY
ENVOYS
```

I will note also that [Merriam-Webster does also countenance /an/ for *envelope*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envelope). However, few if any other *en-* words can be pronounced /an/.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like it is a short enough list to just remember word-by-word.  Out of curiosity, how did you search that dictionary - I wasn't able to figure out how to do such a complex query on the online search (or do you have to download it?).

Comment: Yep, I downloaded it and ran this command `grep '^EN' cmudict.0.7a | grep '  AA' | perl -pe 's/\(1\)//' | cut -f 1 -d\ | sort -u`

Comment: (That second grep command actually two spaces before the `AA`, which seems to have been swallowed up here into one space.)

Comment: It looks like all the words in that list are nouns.  Is there a connection between noun/verb and _ahn/en_?

Answer (score 3):

`En-` is pronounced in French roughly like English's `ahn`. Most words beginning with `en-` have a French origin, explaining this behavior. When in doubt, if the word looks French, go with `ahn`. Of course that doesn't work for all cases, for example `engage` or `envy`. I don't know of any steadfast rule to follow.

Comment: I disagree about "Most words beginning with `en-` have a French origin". Most words don't. In fact quite a few of them are formed simply by adding the en- prefix to some verb (as in enqueue, engage, entrap, etc.) Here's [a list of 1436 words starting with en-](http://www.morewords.com/?en*) — scrolling through the list and picking words at random, French words are rare.

Comment: It's true; I didn't do any research to back up my claim. I think it's a bit beside the point; the point is more about borrowed French pronunciation causing ambiguities in English. Whether it's "most" or not (also, "most" in what terms - usage? count of words?).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You may be right about numbers (I couldn't get this list from your link); but *engage* and *entrap* have the French prefix, not the English one, according to the OED. I'd say any word that existed in French first was probably taken from French directly. *Enqueue* isn't even in the OED; since it does not exist in French as far as I know, it's probably an English formation. However, even the English suffix *en-* comes directly from French. In short, I think pronouncing `ahn-` for all words of French origin would be rather... courageous, as Sir Humphrey would say.

Comment: @tenfour: What sense can you pick for which "most" would be true? :-) @Cerberus: Ok, I should have been more clear: For most words in English beginning with *en-*, the *en-* is not pronounced *ahn* as in French. Seems you agree. :-) The link is this; Markdown ate the final \*: `http://www.morewords.com/?en*`

Comment: The French pronunciation of 'en' is most certainly not like 'ahn'.  'Ahn' looks like an Americanism, actually.  The french 'en' is pronounced similarly to RP's 'on' (though the Americans rarely pronounce 'o' that way and have modified it to 'ah'), although the French would barely pronounce the 'n' in 'en' so it's kind of hard to write.  I dunno where you get 'ahn' from though.

Comment: I feel like I have to defend myself on things that are common sense. The pronunciation of 'ahn' is probably just not well enough defined, but obviously I am mean "the way English speakers mutate the French 'en-' sound into their language". It's just a lot easier to say 'ahn'. You are right that 'on' also works and to some might be closer.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, most of the *en-* words are of French origin. However, majority of them are pronounced |*en*|, as in *envy*. It is not uncommon to hear some of them mispronounced |*ahn*|. This is rife and quite acceptable in America, most especially for the word *envelope*.

All the compound French-derived words beginning with *en* are pronounced *|ahn|*. *En route* can also be pronounced as written.

Comment: In British English you hear "envelope" with both /'ɛn-/ (like "end") and /'ɒn-/ (like "on"), the latter I think being a half-naturalised version of a French pronunciation. Apart from that word, I think the /'ɒn-/ pronunciation is only used for words that are still felt to be foreign, such as "entourage" and "ensuite" (if the latter is regarded as a word). I don't think there's a rule to tell which words come in this category though.

Answer (score -1):

In American English, *en-* is pronounced /ɪn/, or /ɛn/.
In most of the words starting with *en-*, *en-* is a prefix that has origin from French, from Latin *in*.